# How to get the returned data from ajax in my case

Tags: javascript, ajax, ckeditor

I am trying to put my ajax call returned data and other codes in one function.

This is for custom fckeditor plugin.

I have something like

```
  function customTag(editor){

      var id = editor.config.id;
      var instance = this;

      //my custom ajax wrapper…….
      //the 'dbData' is holding the returned data from ajax.
      ajax.onFinished = function(dbData){ console.log(dbData)};

  //I want to return this object and use my ajax returned data
   return {
          title:'Link',
          minWidth : 200,
          minHeight : 200,
          buttons : [CKEDITOR.dialog.okButton, CKEDITOR.dialog.cancelButton],
          contents: [
              {
                  id:'tab',
                  label: 'test here',
                  elements: [                          
                      {
                      type:'select',
                      id:'select box',
                      //I want to use the returned data below
                      items: [[dbData[0],0],[dbData[1],0] ]
                      }
                  ]
              }
          ]
      }
  }

  CKEDITOR.dialog.add('customTag', function(editor){
      return customTag(editor);
  });
```

How would I be able to solve this. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of **async**! You can't do that.

Comment: You need to create a new method that contains your post-success code and supply that method as the success callback to your ajax call

Answer (score 1):

Perform `CKEDITOR.dialog.add()` inside `ajax.onFinished`. In there, create the return object and use it directly for CKEditor. Either that, or use synchronous operations. Something like this:

```
ajax.onFinished = function(dbData){
    var o = {
        title:'Link',
        minWidth : 200,
        minHeight : 200,
        buttons : [CKEDITOR.dialog.okButton, CKEDITOR.dialog.cancelButton],
        contents: [
            {
                id:'tab',
                label: 'test here',
                elements: [                          
                    {
                        type:'select',
                        id:'select box',
                        items: [[dbData[0],0],[dbData[1],0] ] // Use dbData
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    };

    CKEDITOR.dialog.add('customTag', function(editor){
        return o;
    });
};
```

If CKE has issues with calling `dialog.add` after it's been initialized, initialize it inside `ajax.onFinished` too.

Comment: It doesn't work because var o didn't get returned in onFinished method. +1 though

Comment: Why would it need to be returned? If the object is just fed to dialog.add later, why need it after onFinished?